# MongoDB Atlas Search - Multiple terms in search-string with 'and' condition (not 'or')

Tags: mongodb, search, autocomplete, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

In the documentation of MongoDB Atlas search, it says the following for the [`autocomplete`](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/autocomplete/) operator:

> query: String or strings to search for. If there are multiple terms in
> a string, Atlas Search also looks for a match for each term in the
> string separately.

For the [`text`](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/text/) operator, the same thing applies:

> query: The string or strings to search for. If there are multiple
> terms in a string, Atlas Search also looks for a match for each term
> in the string separately.

Matching each term *separately* seems odd behaviour to me. We need multiple searches in our app, and for each we expect less results the more words you type, not more.

Example: When searching for "John Doe", I expect only results with both "John" **and** "Doe". Currently, I get results that match either "John" **or** "Doe".

Is this not possible using MongoDB Atlas Search, or am I doing something wrong?

---

**Update**
Currently, I have solved it by splitting the search-term on space (' ') and adding each individual keyword to a separate must-sub-clause (with the compound operator). However, then the search query no longer returns any results if there is one keyword with only one character. To account for that, I split keywords with one character from those with multiple characters.
The snippet below works, but for this I need to save two generated fields on each document:

- searchString: a string with all the searchable fields concatenated. F.e. "John Doe Man Streetstreet Citycity"
- searchArray: the above string uppercased & split on space (' ') into an array

```
const must = [];
const searchTerms = 'John D'.split(' ');
for (let i = 0; i < searchTerms.length; i += 1) {
    if (searchTerms[i].length === 1) {
      must.push({
        regex: {
          path: 'searchArray',
          query: `${searchTerms[i].toUpperCase()}.*`,
        },
      });
    } else if (searchTerms[i].length > 1) {
      must.push({
        autocomplete: {
          query: searchTerms[i],
          path: 'searchString',
          fuzzy: {
            maxEdits: 1,
            prefixLength: 4,
            maxExpansions: 20,
           },
         },
       });
    }
}
db.getCollection('someCollection').aggregate([
  {
    $search: {
      compound: { must },
    },
  },
]).toArray();
```

---

**Update 2 - Full example of unexpected behaviour**

Create collection with following documents:

```
db.getCollection('testing').insertMany([{
    "searchString": "John Doe ExtraTextHere"
    }, {
    "searchString": "Jane Doe OtherName"
    }, {
    "searchString": "Doem Sarah Thisistestdata"
    }])
```

Create search index 'default' on this collection:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "searchString": {
        "type": "autocomplete"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Do the following query:

```
db.getCollection('testing').aggregate([
  {
    $search: {
      autocomplete: {
        query: "John Doe",
        path: 'searchString',
        fuzzy: {
          maxEdits: 1,
          prefixLength: 4,
          maxExpansions: 20,
        },
      },
    },
  },
]).toArray();
```

When a user searches for "John Doe", this query returns all the documents that have either "John" OR "Doe" in the path "searchString". In this example, that means all 3 documents. The more words the user types, the more results are returned. This is not expected behaviour. I would expect more words to match less results because the search term gets more precise.

Comment: could you share an example query, results, and example docs?

Comment: @Nice-Guy Thank you for your reaction. I've updated the post. Does this info clarify the situation?

Comment: this helps a bit. Now, Two other things that would be helpful are a few sample docs returned and the corresponding index definition.

Comment: @Nice-Guy I've updated once more with full example. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Ok great! Thank you for your persistence. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

An `edgeGram` tokenization strategy might be better for your use case because it works left-to-right.

Try this index definition take from the [docs](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/index-definitions/#autocomplete):

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "searchString": [
        {
          "type": "autocomplete",
          "tokenization": "edgeGram",
          "minGrams": 3,
          "maxGrams": 10,
          "foldDiacritics": true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Also, add change your query clause from must to filter. That will exclude the documents that do not contain all the tokens.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've changed the index to your example and when I run the same search-query for "John Doe", it still matches with the 3 documents. So it still matches on "John" or "Doe".

Comment: @Lowie I added one more bit where you should change the must to a filter. Can you try that?

Comment: I'm also going to set up your index and test it out and ensure my suggestion works. Standby. I will post tomorrow.